# Wrapper div around .col no height?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm both using Bootstrap 3 and trying to modularize my styles like this:
(the empty `<span>s` are generated by React, don't know how to get rid of them...)

**html**

```
<div class="row">
    <span></span>
    <div class="Module">
        <span></span>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <span></span>
            <div class="thumbnail-wrapper">
                <span><img alt="My something" class="img-thumbnail" src="/static/media/avatar.96308863.png"></span>
                <div class="img-thumbnail-close-btn hidden">
                    <span><span class="fa-stack fa-1x"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x white-background"></i><i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x black-border"></i><i class="fa fa-times fa-stack-1x"></i></span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`Module` has no height but `col-xs-*` and `row` does.

- Why?
- And how can I give `Module` full height?

Comment: module only has height attached to whatever is in the divs inside

Answer (score 4):

`.Module` doesn't have any height because the `.col-` classes are floated in Bootstrap 3. When an item is floated it is taken out of the normal document flow and doesn't take up space. If `.col-` don't take up space then `.Module` has no height. `.row` has height because it has a built in [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) that clears the floats of `.col-`.

To fix this you can add `overflow: hidden;` to `.Module` to clear the floats or use a [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).

You might also want to consider moving `.Module` to the `.row` element depending on the styles your applying, i.e. `background-color`.

#### Uncleared Floats

```css
@import url( 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' );

.Module {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="Module">

    <div class="col-xs-6">
      Some content here
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6">
      Some content here
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Cleared Floats

```css
@import url( 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' );

.Module {
  background-color: gold;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="Module">

    <div class="col-xs-6">
      Some content here
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6">
      Some content here
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `overflow: hidden;` makes .Module a block element which is no good as I want 4 items in each row... It doesnt happen in your snippet... Ill just update my example with the full code...

Comment: I could use ´.Module { overflow: hidden; display: inline; }´ but that removes both width and height again. Why is this?

Comment: You really should include your CSS too, markup isn't enough. I have no idea if you've modified/overwritten Bootstrap classes or even what the purpose of `.Module` is and how it affects everything else without the CSS. Please create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Typically one doesn't inject elements between the row and column classes in Bootstrap.

Comment: Found this in the BS docs: "Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows."

Indeed if I move col-xs-3 class to the .Module div, the problem is gone...

Answer (score 1):

just use `clear:both` before closing `.module` div,

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="Module">
        <div class="col-xs-6">Some content here</div>

        <div class="col-xs-6">Some content here</div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this works, adding extra markup over using CSS is _"old hat"_ and goes against some best practices, i.e. adding extraneous markup.

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to "give .Module full height", any containers of `.Module` must be full height too.

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

.container, .row {
    height: 100%;
}

.Module {
    background: gold;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/k72NcpVATe